# With nixos can I install a nodejs package globally?

Tags: npm, nixos, nixpkgs

Say I'd like to install `@squoosh/cli`, this package is mentioned in nixpkgs [here](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/search?q=squoosh). Is there a way to specify the package in `configuration.nix`, or in the home-manager, to have it be installed by `nixos-rebuild`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the packages in `node-packages.json` appear in `pkgs.nodePackages`.

In NixOS, you can add it as follows:

```hs
{ pkgs, ... }: {

  # ...

  environment.systemPackages = [
    pkgs.nodePackages."@squoosh/cli"
  ];

}
```

In Home Manager it's similar, but `home.packages` instead of `environment.systemPackages`.

EDIT: Some node packages are packaged differently. It's worth giving [search.nixos.org](https://search.nixos.org/packages) a try.
Personally I don't think any of the current node packaging methods work well for Nixpkgs. The implementation of [dynamic derivations](https://github.com/NixOS/rfcs/pull/92) will likely lead to a significantly improved solution.

Comment: this doesn't work on 22 and on i think. I tried but it didn't. Instead there a .npm-global folder and .npmrc placed for that purpose so i think it's easier to install npm packages globally now.

Comment: `pkgs.nodePackages` is still around, although this specific package does not build anymore. I don't see any extra node infrastructure in Nixpkgs though, specifically no `.npm-global` or `.npmrc` files.

Comment: Surprisingly i didn't change anything on this setup though, i just installed and worked lol. you can see my setup here. I don't want to mislead anyone, just letting people know. [here](https://github.com/TheoOliveira/dotfiles-nix)